# Subgit --authors-file not mapped, in the git the authors.txt is empty

Tags: git, gitlab, subgit

I use subgit to import a svn repository to a local git.

```
$ subgit import --authors-file authors.txt https://foobar.com:8443/svn/project/ gitproject.git
```

Unfortunately, the users apper in my gitlab as:

```
svnuser@localhost
```

I noticed that the authors.txt in the gitproject.git is only an empty file with the introductory header.

Even though in the log-file there is a correct authors.txt (copied full path and opened in explorer):

```
authorsFile = C:/foo/bar/authors.txt
```

I tried several ways to set `username = foo bar <user.name@foo.bar>`like it is written in the git-users-mapping but no change. If the wrong format is used, will the *real* authors.txt be empty?

How can I make subgit take my authors.txt file?

Comment: I've got a question have you fulfilled the authors file with the actual svn-to-git users mapping? and whether the authors.txt file in the command is the correct path to the file?

Comment: The users mapping should be fulfilled. I also tried svn user_name or user_name@localhost but it didn't work. Also the file path is correct. See latest edit for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to use import with preliminary configuration. For this, first run the 'configure' command:

```
subgit configure --svn-url https://foobar.com:8443/svn/project gitproject.git
```

then edit gitproject.git/subgit/authors.txt and fulfill it with actual users mapping. After that run the import:

```
subgit import gitproject.git
```

This file would definitely work.